# What is the LONGEST Tour operated by travel companies?

Tags: tours, factoids, long-haul, long-term, statistics

I remember 6 years ago, discovering "The Great South American Journey" operated by Gap adventures (now G Adventures), a 5 month trip around the continent (although essentially a bunch of their smaller tours joined together).

Then this year, I found [this](http://www.africantrails.co.uk/tour/ultimate-trans-africa-uk-to-turkey): a **43 week** tour of Africa, covering something like **28 countries** in that time.

I was wondering - two parts, what's the longest official tour offered in the world in terms of time travelling, and which official tour covers the most number of countries?

Comment: Wow!  I did the trans-Africa route back in the early 80's and it was only half that long!

Comment: what route did that entail back then??

Comment: Basically, South Africa -> Kenya -> Nigeria -> Algeria -> Morocco -> Spain -> London.  (Obviously that list isn't complete, I'm just giving the basic turning points.)

Comment: I heard back in 2006 or so that companies were starting up some round-the-world cruises. I don't know if they actually did them, but that might be interesting to look into.

Comment: must be nice to be able to take a year off and just travel the world...

Comment: Agreed, but I suspect if one did the 43 week tour, it'd be remarkably hard to return to a normal job afterwards ;)

Comment: @MarkMayo: it may also lead to an enlightenment to what one's real goal in life is (rather than just M-F, 9-5)

Comment: Round-the-world cruises [don't take that long](http://travel.usatoday.com/cruises/post/2011/11/holland-america-cruise-ship-world-2013/562261/1).

Comment: Sydney to Los Angeles...

Comment: Depending on your definition of a "tour," the answer could be an indefinite period of time, since most cruise lines allow for one to live on the ship indefinitely. In fact, [it is in most cases cheaper to retire on a cruise ship than to live in a nursing home](http://www.snopes.com/travel/trap/retire.asp).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A two-year tour of [World Heritage sites](http://veryfirstto.com/experiences/view/every-world-heritage-site-in-1-holiday/) (962 places) is now available, offered by a British luxury company. By the way, it costs about 1 million pounds. It claims to cover all the sites if they are safely accessible.

[The Daily Mail](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/femail/article-2295636/Around-world--962-Unesco-sites-Luxury-experience-company-offers-ultimate-trip-long-TWO-YEARS-990-000-spare.html) lists some of the stops.

Comment: I was about to add that one....

Comment: I don't think this tour is still being offered.

Answer (score 16):

[This Russian company](http://www.go-cruise.ru/cruise.phtml?id=19478) offers a world-wide cruise for the 140 days, from New Zealand to Norway (being honest, there are no countries from both Americas :).

There are over 100 cities in 31 countries being visited during this cruise.

Places are from *$77,270* to *$261,070* per person, trip is being made on [Seven Seas Voyager](http://www.google.ru/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Seven%20Seas%20Voyager).

I think search for another world-wide tours by ship is very perspective.

Comment: while it's not as long in length of time, it does sure have quite the country count, so awarding the bounty for that.

Answer (score 12):

Ozbus offer a 29 week tour of South America, starting and finishing in Quito.

http://www.oz-bus.com/oz-bus-south-america/oz-bus-south-america.aspx

**Update:
Ozbus have sadly ceased trading as of april 2012**

Comment: I applaud those who can spend 7 months travelling.

Comment: Website appears to be offline.

Comment: Yeah they went bankrupt in April, apparently.

Comment: What's with the random downvote i got 8 years on. The answer was correct and accurate at the time of posting. The answer was updated to reflect the fact that OzBus have ceased trading. It seems a little harsh to down-vote me because my powers of clairvoyance weren't up to scratch.

Answer (score 11):

[Sydney - London by bus](http://www.oz-bus.com/london-sydney/london-sydney-overview.aspx) was the longest i could think of, but it's only 92 days and crosses 18 countries.

Comment: oz-bus no longer operates.

Answer (score 11):

Would going on a cargo ship count as a tour? In that case there is a [tour operator](http://www.cargoshipcruises.nl/) offering various tours, of which their [offers on oceania](http://www.cargoshipcruises.nl/oceania.htm), are quite long. One example being

> Rotterdam-Dunkerque-Le Havre-New
>   York-Savannah-Kingston-Manzanillo-Panama
>   Canal-Papeete-Laukota-Noumea-Brisbane-Sydney-Melbourne-Tauranga-Napier-Panama
>   Canal-Manzanillo-Savannah-Philadelphia-Tilbury-Rotterdam, duration ca.
>   84 days

Especially since they offer intermediate stops, you can prolong this "tour" for quite some time

Answer (score 11):

MadVenture Travel is now offering:

[LONDON TO SYDNEY OVERLAND (via Africa & central Asian silk road)](http://madventure.travel/expeditions/london-to-sydney-overland-via-africa/via-africa-central-asian-silk-road/)

[image: map of the crazy route that they're doing]

which promises to be a 64 week, 61 country odyssey!!

From their site:

> A 64 week in-depth overland expedition from London to Sydney
>   travelling through Africa, the Middle East, central Asia and
>   Australasia visiting highlights and natural wonders of 61 countries
>   including UK, France, Spain, Morocco, Western Sahara, Mauritania,
>   Senegal, Gambia, Guinea Bissau, Guinea, Sierra Leone, Liberia, Ivory
>   Coast, Ghana, Togo, Benin, Nigeria, Cameroon, Equatorial Guinea,
>   Gabon, Congo, Democratic Republic of Congo, Angola, Namibia, Botswana,
>   South Africa, Lesotho, Swaziland, Mozambique, Zimbabwe, Zambia,
>   Malawi, Tanzania, Rwanda, Uganda, Kenya, Ethiopia, Sudan, Egypt,
>   Jordan, Syria, Lebanon, Turkey, Georgia, Armenia, Azerbaijan,
>   Turkmenistan, Uzbekistan, Tajikistan, Kyrgyzstan, Kazakhstan, Russia,
>   Mongolia, China, Laos, Vietnam, Cambodia, Thailand, Malaysia,
>   Singapore, Indonesia and Australia.

Comment: The website no longer seems active.

Comment: This tour is not available. Here is a shorter version from the same company: https://madventure.co.uk/london-to-sydney-overlandtour/

Answer (score 10):

UKTOOZ appears to offer a 28 Week London to Sydney trip

http://uktooz.com/

> A 28 week in-depth overland expedition from London to Sydney visiting the highlights and natural wonders of over 23 countries including Turkey, Iran, Pakistan, India, Nepal, Tibet, China, Laos, Vietnam, Cambodia, Thailand, Malaysia, Singapore, Indonesia and Australia!

Comment: Website no longer seems to work.

Comment: Website redirects to http://madventure.co.uk/ now.

Comment: Indeed. Not yesterday when I checked. They have some awesome concept tours listed.

Answer (score 10):

One day, while travelling online with google maps, I zoomed onto [Ushuaia](http://maps.google.fr/maps?hl=fr&ll=-54.810987,-68.297013&spn=0.002708,0.005386&t=h&z=18) and got caught by a ship named [Peace Boat](http://www.peaceboat.org/english/).

This ship takes passengers for cruises around the world that last about 100 days.

EDIT, Nov,2016: Google Maps has updated its satellite imagery. Peace Boat is no longer visible.

Comment: hah, I was speaking to someone recently whose sister just finished a stint on that.  Well spotted sighting!

Answer (score 9):

Since we don't really care about the mode of transportation:

143 nights: http://www.rssc.com/cruises/VOY121024H/Itinerary.aspx

115 nights: [Silver Sea World Cruise](http://www.silversea.com/destinations/world-cruise-2012/)

115 nights: [Holland America World](http://www.hollandamerica.com/find-cruise-vacation/CruiseDetails.action?destCode=W&portCode=&shipCodeSearch=&durationCode=4&dateCode=&flexibleMonths=false&noOfFlexibleMonths=1&pageNumber=5&voyageCode=A310&webItineraryIdForAudit=WW3115)

At one point there was a [335 night cruise](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100125130710AAzvlWB) but as far as I can tell that company is now out of business 2010.

**Had to add this**

Around the world by Freighters:

[125 days starting from Houston](http://www.freighter-travel.com/travel-itineraries.html)

Answer (score 9):

G Adventures still has an [82 day trip](http://www.gadventures.com/trips/great-south-american-journey-rio-to-quito/JRQ/2012/).

Answer (score 4):

Viking offers a **245-day** [round-the-world cruise](https://www.vikingcruises.com/oceans/cruise-destinations/world-grand/2020-world-cruise/index.html), which starts (and ends) in London. It visits 53 countries on six continents.

[image: Itinerary of Viking World Cruise]

Answer (score 1):

This one kinda straddles the line between accommodation and travel, but I believe it still qualifies.

There are several cruise ships that offer the public a chance to lease a cabin for an extended period of time (in some cases up to 60 years) and live there full time if you so choose. These vessels are called residential yachts. You can live (and sometimes work) on board the ship as it travels round the world. The destinations are usually voted on by the residents.

These leases can be quite expensive and also come with a monthly fee to cover cost of living, maintenance and upkeep of the ship.

A notable example was the [MS The World](https://aboardtheworld.com) ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MS_The_World)), launched in 2003. Currently all of its cabins are owned, but there are several other residential yachts that (as of 2020) have available cabins.

Two such ships (as of Mar 2020) are :

- [StoryLines](https://www.storylines.com)
- [Utopia](http://www.utopiaresidences.com)

These aren't cheap, but i think you'll struggle to find a longer tour than a 60 year lease on one of these vessels.