# how to plan a round the world trip?

Tags: planning, around-the-world

On my bucket list there is a Round the World trip. I will start from Europe and I’d like to visit Asia/Australia/any pacific island/South America. Is there any website that allows to build a trip like this for a good price? Let’s say I have 2000 EUR - how I could find most optimal itinerary to fit my budget and visit more places?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "build"? Are you looking for a website to put together a round the world airfare or are you looking for it tell you where to go, where to stay, how to fly?  The later is called a Travel Agent.

Comment: Or punch "round the world ticket" into your nearest search engine, and you'll find various web sites that will help you plan such a trip and will probably sell you tickets, too.

Comment: This is far, far too broad to be answerable. You learn about the places you want to go, and the things you want to do there, and when you want to do it, and what order you want to do them in, and at the very last step you piece together how you want to get from place to place. There's no tool to do it because you literally have millions of options to choose from. Or, just buy a guidebook that tells you how to do. Or, just book a [round-the-world cruise](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/13484/1480).

Comment: Just did one but there are just too many variables for it to be possible to make an answer that is not as long as a book!

Comment: Planning it is half the fun! As you go, you can all kinds of **specific** question here about how to get between two places, or how to choose which pacific island to include, and so on. Just make sure not to ask for "best" or other subjective decision-making. Ask for the facts you need in order to make your decision.

Comment: 2000 Euros??   I would be surprised if you could get the air tickets for that.  I did two long round the world trips while growing up, we spent upwards of 10x at (for three people) more than 30 years ago--and we were traveling as cheaply as we reasonably could.

Answer (score 1):

The OneWorld airline alliance has special around-the-world fares that offer a significant discount over point-to-point tickets, with flexibility to change dates, and unlimited mileage.  You pay based on how many continents you want to visit.  Other airline alliances also offer around-the-world fares, although those tend to be priced based on mileage.  You can build an around-the-world trip at the [OneWorld web site](http://oneworld.com).

Comment: Thank you, the Oneworld RTW tool looks very useful, i didn't know it