# What's the longest scheduled public bus ride in the world?

Tags: buses, factoids, long-haul

I'm about to take a depressingly long bus ride in Latin America and am wondering what the longest scheduled public bus ride in the world is.

By 'scheduled' I mean for there to be a regularly operating connection between the start and destination locations, without switching buses. Besides the fact that they no longer seem to operate, this would disqualify something like [oz-bus](http://www.oz-bus.com/).

By 'longest' I'm tending to favour distance over duration, though either way, circular repetitive journeys would obviously be excluded.

Edit (August 2017):
I took the bus from Lima to Rio de Janeiro. Just over five days from beginning to end. [A write up](http://babakfakhamzadeh.com/article/this-is-the-longest-bus-ride-in-the-world).

Comment: WHen I was in Argentina, I was told about one that takes a week, from Caracas to Buenos Aires. Not sure if hearsay or real though.

Comment: Allegedly there was a plan to have a bus from Kashmir to Birmingham taking 12 to 13 days  (http://indiatoday.intoday.in/story/kashmir-to-united-kingdom-bus-service-6500-kms/1/222084.html)

Comment: @MarkMayo That's Ormeno that does Caracas to BA, but you switch busses in Lima. And I saw the article you mention, but I'm not putting a lot of stock in it.

Comment: Some sick part of me still wants to do the 7 day trip, just to see what it's like. Cama suite though, hopefully :)

Comment: There's a travel company that actually lists a price for the Kashmir to Birmingham trip at http://us.riya.travel/travelupdate-details/bus-service-from-united-kingdom-to-india. But, it very much seems the connection does not exist.

Comment: Intrigued, I found a regularly scheduled bus departing from Manzhouli arriving Moscow (overnight at Irkutsk).  It's got to be in the running.

Comment: @GayotFow that's nuts. But, overnight in Irkutsk only? That's only a quarter of the way to Moscow from Manzhouli.

Comment: Yeah, Irkutsk is the first stop where the rest of the journey is in Russia's interior.  Plus there's a major junction with the railroad there. Nearly everyone is plastered on vodka, few police.  The buses were already outmoded in the communist era, today they are about 30 - 35 years old, poorly ventilated, some with no heating, no lighting. No chance to get food. Plus passengers are expected to help push if the bus gets caught in a snow drift.  I have a friend who regularly takes the bus from Syzran to Tver and she fills me in on the 'pleasantries'.  Your journey in Latin America is a waltz :)

Comment: Even if the stop in Irkutsk is a change of busses, this sounds like a contender for the longest bus ride. Care adding it as an answer?

Comment: As for that oz-bus, they changed modes of transport.  As far as I'm concerned the question needs qualification, though--do bus-based tours count?  Back in the 70s I was aware of Kathmandu-London, one bus all the way but it was for seeing the countries you passed through, not simply to get from one end to the other.  Space permitting you could negotiate a ride for part of the distance.

Comment: @CGCampbell The fact that I'm amazed by a China to Moscow connection does not mean it also qualifies as a valid answer. The implication was, however, that Irkutsk to Moscow was direct. Anyway, it seems to me the question is clear and, as I also pointed out, this website has many similar longest/furthest questions that have been accepted as valid questions and required similar, or more, legwork to answer. Here's just one: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/5149/what-is-the-longest-tour-operated-by-travel-companies

Comment: @LorenPechtel A bus-based tour is not a regularly operating public transport connection. So, no. It would not count.

Comment: @MastaBaba Such runs are scheduled although generally seasonal.  Space available most anyone (the driver(s) can reject someone they don't want) can ride although the price for less than the full trip is negotiated, not fixed.  That part of it is pretty close, what I was questioning is that is the sightseeing part of it.

Comment: @LorenPechtel Ok. I'd say that if the objective is sightseeing, and not getting from A to B, the nature of the journey is very different from what we normally associate with 'public transport', no?

Comment: Do none of the buses between Perth and Melbourne or Sydney utilize the same bus throughout without switching?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Lima to Rio de Janeiro. Six hours more than Lima to São  Paulo. DW has a documentary on this trip. My personal longest is SP to Recife - 54 hours (scheduled for 48 hours)

Comment: Both https://www.tripadvisor.ca/ShowTopic-g303506-i1199-k9198150-New_bus_route_Lima_Peru_to_Rio-Rio_de_Janeiro_State_of_Rio_de_Janeiro.html and http://highwaybrazil.com/brazil/rio-to-lima-peru-the-world-longest-bus-drive/ says this started at the end of Jan 2016 so no wonder Carl from Busbud's excellent answer doesn't contain it.

Comment: Well well well. I'm quite amazed Ormeno is still offering this: The price is steep and the ticket is not easy to book.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_ODFlqURxY

Comment: FYI, Google Maps says it's 4800 km.

Answer (score 54):

I work at [Busbud](http://www.busbud.com), where we're working to aggregate all the world's bus providers and routes. I had a look though our database. We're sure we don't know about everything yet, but we've found a lot of routes. There are several long routes in South and North America. I compared them using the driving distance calculated by Google Maps.

Looking for trips with no transfers, where it seems the same vehicle travels the whole route, here are the top contenders:

**South America:**

- 6118 km: Lima, Peru to Rio de Janeiro, Brazil (Ormeño) - via Sao Paulo and Rio Branco, Acre, Brazil. [DW Documentary](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_ODFlqURxY) on it's launch.
- 5582 km: Lima, Peru to Buenos Aires, Argentina (Ormeño) - via Santiago, Chile.

There are [documentaries and tv reports about the long direct routes on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1agWg41Oq2c) where you can see the same coach goes all the way through.

**North America:**

- 4644 km / 85 hours: Los Angles, California, USA to San Salvador, El Salvador (Usa Tours) - Once a week via Guadalajara and Guatemala City.
- 4607 km / 65 hours: [Los Angles, California, USA to New York, New York, USA (Greyhound Lines)](https://www.busbud.com/en/bus-schedules-results/LosAngeles,California,UnitedStates/NewYork,NewYork,UnitedStates) - via Kansas, Pittsburgh and Philadelphia.  Greyhound runs two of these every day.
- 3538 km: Saint Paul, Minnesota, USA to Morelia, Michoacán, Mexico (Transportes Chayo).
- 3254 km / 44 hours: [Guadalajara, Jalisco, Mexico to Chicago, Illinois, USA (Turimex)](https://www.busbud.com/en/bus-guadalajara-chicago/r/9ewmx6-dp3wj6) - There are several other buses from Chicago to Mexico but this is the most frequent, at least daily, and the longest we're sure is a direct bus.

**Europe:**

- 3631 km: Braunschweig, Germany to Grozny, Chechnya, Russia (KVN) - The route is currently a bit longer than normal since it's detouring around the entire eastern Ukraine through Belarus.
- 3558 km: Burgas, Bulgaria to Liverpool, England, United Kingdom (Sofia Bus) - via Maribor, Stuttgart, Mannheim, Paris, London, Manchester.

**Africa**

- 1868 km: [Johannesburg, South Africa to Lilongwe, Malawi (Intercape)](https://www.busbud.com/en-ca/bus-johannesburg-lilongwe/r/ke7fyn-kv808c)

Comment: Awesome! Your Lima to Sao Paulo is too short as it runs through Rio Branco, in Acre, making the total distance closer to 5700km.

Comment: I'm not able to find that connection to Grozny on your site. And I find KVN is some Russian TV show :)

Comment: Also, no luck on connections between China and Russia?

Comment: http://www.kvn24.de/

Comment: The only China-Russia connections we know are over around Vladivostock, they're much shorter (~1000km)

Comment: @Carl:  I love how 1000 km counts as "short" in the context of this question.

Comment: I addded the duration info, unfortunately didn't find it for all routes.

Comment: "All passengers are required to get off the bus for cleaning in Sudbury" - the bus or the passengers?  :)

Comment: @chx mentions 96 hours in another answer for the Lima to Sao Paulo trip. I personally asked for the duration of this journey earlier this year, while in Lima and 96 hours *feels* about right.

Comment: Also, I'm getting quite different distances for the two South America trips. Lima to BA (via Santiago): 4793km. Lima to SP (via Rio Branco): 5621km. (Also, there's Santiago to Sao Paulo (via Urugaiana) (this is the bus I'm taking): 3269km.

Comment: According to the Ormeno website, the Lima to Buenos Aires connection indeed runs through Santiago, but not through La Paz.

Comment: I suddenly have a grave urge to hop on a particular bus in Braunschweig! Wow.

Comment: For the Calgary-Toronto, people are required to get off the bus in Winnipeg, MB (and at some other stop in the Prairies) as well, for cleaning.

Answer (score 13):

It's very hard to prove which one is the longest. There's a 96 hour ride by Expreso Ormeño from Lima to Sao Paulo. I can't find proof that Birmingham bus ever happened.

Comment: The Lima to Sao Paulo bus departs once a week.

Comment: I know a friend of mine who came from Russia in a bus, on a 5-day long bus trip. If that's true or not, I can't exactly tell.

Comment: 6.000km trip you can find pictures [here](http://viatrolebus.com.br/2014/06/com-quase-6-mil-km-linha-de-onibus-que-liga-sao-paulo-ao-peru-e-a-maior-do-mundo/) (article in portuguese). Brazil is a large country where bus trips are common, Not hard to find 2 days trips from São Paulo to the northen states. Also check rules about stops, in Brazil there are a few laws about stops frequency, for example the bus must stop each 4 hours and dirvers must switch each 8hrs, etc

Comment: that happens in the canadian example below, but its the drivers that change, no transfers (passenger does not have to get off the bus) that I think the OP cares about.

Answer (score 9):

I once took a bus from Toronto, ON (Canada) to Yellowknife, NWT. It took 80 hours. However, I seem to recall switching buses once in Calgary, AB. A search on (search at [Greyhound](http://www.greyhound.ca) suggests there is a transfer in Winnipeg, which I don't remember). That makes it about 2000km. Or 3400km if it was Calgary (it doesn't cut through the US).

Comment: That might be a contender for the longest North American bus ride. :)

Comment: A colleague once traveled from Toronto to Mexico City by Greyhound many many years ago. Current Greyhound website informs it takes 78h but includes 5 transfers

Comment: While Toronto to Calgary seems to currently require a transfer in Winnipeg, Calgary to Toronto appears to be one bus without any transfers. It takes 52 hours, 20 minutes if it runs on time.

Comment: I took the Calgary to Toronto bus last week, ran like clock-work on the departing each stop on the dot.

Comment: @I've done the Calgary (well, Banff to Calgary first), to Toronto, gave up in Winnipeg and switched to train ;)

Answer (score 6):

Harare Zimbabwe to Dare Salaam Tanzania 2,285 km Taqwa and Falcon Buses is the lonngest in Africa 52 Hours journey.

Answer (score 4):

In Europe, Eurolines operates relatively frequent bus drives between major cities and holiday favourites. The longest direct line I could find on their website rides from Hamburg (Germany), to Burgas (Bulgaria), takes 40 hours and covers just over 2300 km (assuming they take the shortest route). There might be longer ones, ...
EDIT: From their French site, they also operate a direct line from Paris to Casablanca (Maroc). Also just over 2300 km, takes roughly 37 hours.

I remember from my visit to Argentina that they have very long bus rides with luxury buses including sleeping facility. I looked it up in the Lonely Planet (2008 issue) and found a depressing long ride from Buenos Aires to Rio Gallegos that takes 36-40 hours. The distance is about 2500 km (Google Maps). I am not sure it is a direct line, but wouldn't be surprised if it was.

Comment: I also wouldn't be surprised if that Argentine connection is direct. It's pretty much par for the course in Latin America.

Comment: That European bus connection is a good find. Eurolines also used to go to Moscow, but that seems to be discontinued.

Comment: If you take the bus from Paris to Casablanca, there would presumably be [a break in the driving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strait_of_Gibraltar) in the middle.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert True, but it would still be the same service on the same bus. Nevertheless, this distance is 'only' 2400km.

Comment: From the German site: Düsseldorf - Istanbul, over 2500 km, 43 hours.

Answer (score 3):

Why are you excluding the oz-bus?

While the London - Sydney route breaks your conditions, what about London - Kathmandu?

Regularly scheduled, one vehicle.  47 days.  (Note that I have taken two such trips, both with budget operators {necessity--most of them had rules that excluded us.}  On schedule?!  No way!)  And they're back in business.

Comment: Clever, and one heck of a journey! Though their website seems to have information from 2011-2012 (that's when the last trip dates are listed), so I'm not so sure about "regularly scheduled." I suppose there's also question at some point as to what continues a public bus vs a tour.

Comment: @ZachLipton Note that at least in the past there were many companies running such trips.  And if you find one and it has a seat you can negotiate with the driver for passage.  That's what we did for Delhi -> Tehran (but due to breakdowns we ended up leaving them in Shiraz.)