# Is there a resource that lists long trip bus companys operating by city, in Europe?

Tags: online-resources, buses

I just recently discovered a new bus company operating where I live with interesting international destinations.

This makes me wonder how many more can there be that I am not aware of.

Is there a resource that lists long trips / international trips bus company's, per city, in Europe?

Comment: Have you checked "Buses Magazine", the hard-copy monthly issue?

Answer (score 2):

[BusBud](https://www.busbud.com/en/sitemap/all-cities-by-bus/wc/0) will do this.  The main page is just a Kayak-like bus search engine, but towards the bottom of the front page, there's a "Browse All Cities" button, which takes you to the page I linked above.  Once you're there, you can narrow down by country and city.

Comment: A tip of the hat to @Carl, who actually works at BusBud, and who made me aware of the website in [this thread.](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/56357/whats-the-longest-scheduled-public-bus-ride-in-the-world/56478)

Comment: I was debating mentioning BusBud. It's very informative, but it doesn't list bus companies per city as the OP wanted.

Comment: The BusBud interface seem to offer buses to/from all combination of cities it is aware of and only after you've clicked through a quite tedious selection of countries and cities, you come to a prefilled search form just to discover that BusBud finds 'No Departure' for your selection.